# Will I be able to board the flight if Vietnam tourist e-visa starts on the day of arrival but the departure is on an evening before?

Tags: visa, vietnam

I have a tourist visa to Vietnam starting 28th Jul. My flight from Bangalore, India is on 27th Jul 11:00 PM IST (12:30 am 28th Jul, in Vietnam). The airline is SINGAPORE AIRLINES. I hope I will be able to board the flight as the arrival is 28th Jul and even the departure is 28th Jul in Vietnam.

Comment: What did the airline say when you asked?

Comment: Vietnam won't ever see you with in invalid visa. But your airline sees you getting on a plane with an invalid visa; so that's 100% up to the airline. They could decide either way.